# How to edit LoadableDetachableModel in Apache Wicket

Tags: java, apache, wicket

I am using loadableDetachableModel to show some components and it gets the data that I wanted first time by calling webservice in load method. But users do some operations like insert or delete to that model. So I don't wanna call that webservice except first time.

So the code be like:

```
myLoadableDetachablModel = new LoadableDetachableModel<List<MyType>>() {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Override
protected List<MyType> load() {
    // I don't want to touch DB except very first time
    List<MyType> neededObjects = myService.getMyMethod();
    return neededObjects;
}};
```

Do you have any suggestions for me? thanks

Comment: I'm a bit confused - `LoadableDetachableModel` seems to be exactly what you want. What behavior of it is not what you like?

Comment: Whenever that loadabledetachablemodel needed, it calls load method so that I would get the result of myService.getMyMethod(). In this case, I was loosing "added" and "removed" objects from that model, a modified list was being replaced by the result of myService.getMyMethod(). Anyway, a solution that @svenmeier suggested, worked fine for me. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many projects use their custom implementation for this use-case:

```
public abstract class InitializingModel<T> extends AbstractReadOnlyModel<T> {

    private boolean initialized;
    private T t;

    public T getObject() {
       if (initialized == false) {
            t = init();
            initialized = true;
       }
       return t;
    }

    protected abstract T init();
}
```

Note that this will keep your model object T in the page tree during serialization of pages and sessions.

Comment: Thank you @svenmeier, that was the solution that I was looking for.

Comment: @svenmeier is there an advantage to doing it this way as opposed to overriding `LoadableDetachableModel#detach()` not to detach the data?

Comment: IMHO overriding LDM makes it harder to reason about your Code.